# dell SNMP raid disk no data

Tags: dell, snmp, dell-perc, mib

I'm trying to monitor data with SNMP for disks in a raid attached to some servers. From what I understand the raid is configured with PERC and PERC does have a MIB associated with it. I've downloaded PERC.mib and AryMgr.mib and have tried to browse the data with a MIB browser (snmp v2) but any of the OIDs in these mibs return "No Data."

Because this exists and the result of the SNMP GET is "No Data" I think I am missing some configuration on the servers. Has anyone experienced this or has any suggestions as to what I might be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to install Dell's OMSA (Openmanage Server Administrator) before you're going to get any data.  A quick search found [How to configure OMSA/SNMP on Linux](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/f/4494/t/19425042.aspx).